# Mesh.Effects input XNA

Tags: c#, .net, matrix, xna

I didnt quite understand whats is the `effect.World` and `effect.View` etc. and why we put the matricies in them?

```
foreach (ModelMesh mesh in model1.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                effect.World = Matrix.CreateWorld(Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Forward, Vector3.Up);
                effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

effect.World is not a matrix representing the world. It is a matrix representing a 3d object's (mesh, model) position and orientation relative to the 3d game world. Each object will have a different effect.World matrix if they are positioned differently &/or pointed differently.

effect.View is a matrix that represents (in an inverted form) the position & orientation of the camera relative to that same 3d game world. Most of the time, there is only one camera, but there can be more (say, a rear view mirror will have it's own view matrix as opposed to the main screen showing the view out the windshield of a car racing game).

1. a model's vertices are hard valued to model local space.
2. Then the effect.World transforms them to game world space.
3. then the effect.View transforms them to camera space.
4. Then the effect.Projection transforms them to 2d screen space and 'volia', your pixel shader knows where to draw what.

Comment: So for every model in the game(assuming each placed in differnet location) i should creat its own matrix that will respresent its location?

Comment: yes, it's location and orientation (rotation) are represented in the same matrix. This matrix is passed to the effect.World. Even if placed in the same location, it is better organization to give each model its own matrix.

Comment: Thanks! And in an unrelated topic, whats `Vector3.Transform` and how does it work?

Answer (score 1):

From MSDN;

[`BasicEffect.World`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.basiceffect.world.aspx)

> Gets or sets the world matrix. **Use this matrix to change the position
>   of the model, using world coordinates**.

[`BasicEffect.View`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.graphics.basiceffect.view.aspx)

> Gets or sets the view matrix. **Use this matrix to change the position
>   and direction of the camera**.

I think bold lines explain what is exactly their difference. Also I found some helpful articles;

- [How to: Use BasicEffect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203926%28v=xnagamestudio.10%29.aspx)
- [Does every Entity in an XNA game need it's own BasicEffect instance?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/36026/does-every-entity-in-an-xna-game-need-its-own-basiceffect-instance)
- [Understanding Half-Pixel and Half-Texel Offsets](http://drilian.com/2008/11/25/understanding-half-pixel-and-half-texel-offsets/)
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/04/05/spritebatch-and-custom-shaders-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb219690(VS.85).aspx

Comment: But shouldnt this matricies be the general matricies of the game itself? I mean, how could any model have a different position and direction of the camera? There should be only 1 camera and 1 world, isnt it?

Comment: I'm not a XNA developer but there could be a lot of camera? Why don't agree on camera count?

Comment: How can you see multiple things at once?
And i still dont get this, you apply to each effect the game's world, view and projection to "tell" the model where and how he should be represented?
And correct me if im wrong, but we for example move models by creating each model its own world matrix, and create translations to its matrix? if so, then why do we call it "world" if there is no actuall world but alot of world to each model in the game?